# Jade template in Node.JS/Express app can't find external Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have a Node.JS/Express app that uses the Jade template engine.  I have a Javascript file that is in the directory immediately above my *views* directory that contains my Jade views.  Given the code below, I believe that the view *should* be able to find referenced server-side *Javascript file named* `common_routines`, but when the view is requested I get a 404 error saying that the external Javascript file could not be found.  This confuses me because I thought Jade templates execute server side, so why would this trigger a `404 error` from the Jade `render()` call?

**Here is the Jade view:**

```
block content
    script(src="../common_routines.js")
    div(style="padding:5px")
        h4 #{product.name}
    if (product.brand != null)
        p Brand: #{product.brand}
    div(class="img_and_desc")
        img(src=product.imageUrl, class="product_image", align="left")
        if (product.minimumPrice == product.maximumPrice)
            p Price: #[strong #{product.minimumPrice}]
        else
            p Price: #[strong #{product.minimumPrice}] to #[strong #{product.maximumPrice}]
        if (product.cashBack > 0)
            p Cash Back amount: #[strong #{product.cashBack}]
        if (product.freeShipping)
            p(class="text-emphasized-1") *Free Shipping!
        if (product.onSale)
            p(class="text-emphasized-2") Discounted Item
```

Here is a snippet of the call from the route file that renders the view, where the `if (err)` branch is triggered:

```
           res.render(
                'ajax-product-details',
                locals,
                function (err, html) {
                    if (err)
                    // A rendering error occurred.
                        throw new Error("Rendering error(type:" + err.type + ", message: " + err.message);
                    else {
                        // Success. Send back the rendered HTML.
                        res.send(html);
                        return;
                    }
                });
```

Here is the error I see in the WebStorm debugger Console window pane.  Notice that it shows the file reference as **/common_routines.js** *without* the preceding ".." relative directory reference, despite the fact that preceding ".." relative directory reference is plainly visible in the Jade file reference `("script(src="../common_routines.js")):`

```
[Express][127.0.0.1][GET][DESKTOP] 2016-07-20T10:07:34.940Z /common_routines.js?_=1469009245957
(development error handler) Status code(404) message: Not Found
```

Here is the common_routines.js content:

```
function truncateString(str, maxLen)
{
    if (str.length > maxLen)
        return str.substring(0, maxLen - 1) + '&hellip';
    return str;
}

module.exports =
{
    truncateString: truncateString
}
```

As I said, *common_routines.js* is in the directory immediately above the Jade view, so is this external file reference invalid for some reason?:

```
script(src="../common_routines.js")
```

Comment: What path have you set for your public assets in your `app.js` file?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj - app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));  But neither common_routines.js or the view that references that file are in that directory tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only reference static files that are in your `public` folder(if you have set your static assets to be served from that folder, as you have), on your front-end side. You can put your `common_routines.js` file in a folder inside public e.g. `public/js/`. 
Now, you can reference this in your view file using `script(src="/js/common_routines.js")`

In case, you want to use the functions in your jade file, not on front-end js files, you need to include that as a package using `var commonRoutines = require('../common_routines.js');` inside your server side js file. Now, you can pass this object variable along with your context object to your view file. As you stated, you pass locals object to your view file while rendering, you can do it like:

```
var common_routines = require('../common_routines.js');
var locals = { common_routines: common_routines };
res.render( 'ajax-product-details', locals);
```

Now, you can use functions from `common_routines.js` in your `ajax-product-details` file.

Comment: I had tried that approach earlier and it's true that I no longer got the 404 error for the external Javascript file.  However, every time I tried to access a function in the Javascript file from my jade view (E.g. - p #{truncateString(product.description, 400)} ), I got an error in the render() callback with the error type "called_non_callable" and the message indicating the Jade view line with the truncateString() call.  truncateString() is in the externally referenced JS call.  So I moved the JS file back out of the /public dir tree.

Comment: You cannot use your static external js file functions in your jade file. Because jade is rendered on server side while this js file will be available on client side. If you need to include some function from external js file in your jade, you need to include that as a package using `commonRoutines = require('../common_routines.js');` inside your server side js file.

Comment: Thanks.  That pointed me in the right direction, but to make it work I also had to add the commonRoutines variable to the "locals" object I pass to render() so I did: var locals = { common_routines: common_routines } ; res.render( 'ajax-product-details', locals).  Can you add this to your reply along with that last comment so I can accept it?